# Database: What schema is more efficient?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

Which of this approaches is the best? They are all normalized but this options confuses me.

---

### First approach

This approach will have less empty data but will be more divided. It only save the player who try, kick or was expelled in each table.

#### Variant one

```
MatchPlayer(matchId, playerId)
Try(matchId, playerId, tries)
Kick(matchId, playerId, conversions, failedConversions, dropGoals)
Card(matchId, playerId, yellow, red)
```

#### Variant two

```
MatchPlayer(id, matchId, playerId)
Try(matchPlayerId, tries)
Kick(matchPlayerId, conversions, failedConversions, dropGoals)
Card(matchPlayerId, yellow, red)
```

---

### Second approach

This approach will have empty data but will be less divided. It only save in `MatchStats` the players who score or were expelled.

#### Variant one

```
MatchPlayer(matchId, playerId)
MatchStats(matchId, playerId, tries, conversions, failedConversions, dropGoals, yellow, red)
```

#### Variant two

```
MatchPlayer(id, matchId, playerId)
MatchStats(matchPlayerId, tries, conversions, failedConversions, dropGoals, yellow, red)
```

---

### Third approach

This approach will have much more empty data but will be much less divided. It save all the data as zeros even if the player didn't score or was expelled.

```
MatchPlayer(matchId, playerId, tries, conversions, failedConversions, dropGoals, yellow, red)
```

---

### Fourth approach

This approach will have no empty data at all but will be much more divided.

#### Variant one

```
MatchPlayer(matchId, playerId)
Try(matchId, playerId, tries)
Conversion(matchId, playerId, conversions)
FailedConversion(matchId, playerId, failedConversions)
DropGoal(matchId, playerId, dropGoals)
YellowCard(matchId, playerId, yellow)
RedCard(matchId, playerId, red)
```

#### Variant two

```
MatchPlayer(matchPlayerId, matchId, playerId)
Try(matchPlayerId, tries)
Conversion(matchPlayerId, conversions)
FailedConversion(matchPlayerId, failedConversions)
DropGoal(matchPlayerId, dropGoals)
YellowCard(matchPlayerId, yellow)
RedCard(matchPlayerId, red)
```

---

What's your opinion?

Comment: Best for ***what***? How are going to use this data?

Comment: @PM77-1 It's a database in SQLite for an Angular2 app of a rugby club.

Comment: Still not enough information.  What kind of queries are you going to run?  How often will you update the data?

Comment: @PM77-1 The data will be updated one time, just after a match and won't be manipulated any more. The queries will be just SELECT after the first INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third approach seems reasonable - it's a relationship table with attributes describing the relationship.  You have a composite key for the relationship and your attributes have expected values any time the relationship exists.

In terms of efficiency, your table is not particularly wide, so the efficiency of scanning the table to compute aggregate statistics is not compromised.  All of the approaches will have similar performance for queries such as:

- List the stats for all players in a match
- List the stats for a player's matches

These queries will rely on indexing of the **relationship** table in every case, with lookups into the joined tables.  Given the number of rows you might expect in the results per match or per player, the joins are not significant.  However, as noted the third approach eliminates the need for any joins while maintaining an appropriate level of normalization.

Answer (score 1):

I would pick Second Approach, Variant 1. If you only add the data for each player after each match, then query it later, having all of the data in a single table will make most queries simpler (as well as the overall database structure).

While other approaches may be better design-wise, the multi-table joins will just be annoying.

However, I would include a row for every player in the match (with 0 values for tries, etc). This will ensure you don't have to treat them as a special case when compiling statistics. This will, of course, depend upon the actual queries and how you write them, so consider it as an option.

Note that this advice is based upon gut feel, and limited knowledge of your actual application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after asking some teammates they all choosed the third approach, but your explanation was amazing :).

Comment: @J.J.Bocanegra That's OK, I like @MichaelPetito's answer too. Not sure why I thought you would want the `MatchPlayer` table - I think I was assuming that there would be extra columns in it like round number or date, but these would be in the `Match` table anyway. Glad you have an answer, and one thing to remember is that it isn't too difficult to change the data structures later if they don't really suit your needs.